# each prior taking more time to run an operation compared to each both in kdb

Tags: kdb

As per my understanding,
each-both (') when applied on monadic function uses a single thread to perform the operation and each-prior(':) uses all available slaves(threads) to perform an operation.

each internally uses each-both and peach internally uses each-prior.

```
q)each
k){x'y}
q)peach
k){x':y}
```

Out of curiosity, I was checking if each-prior takes less time to perform an operation then each-both but seems like each-prior is taking more time even after the size of the operand in big.

Few observations:

```
q)\t:10000 type '[(1h;2h;3j;4.2)]
3
q)\t:10000 type ':[(1h;2h;3j;4.2)]
120
q)\t:10000 type '[(1000#1.2)]
275
q)\t:10000 type ':[(1000#1.2)]
1154
q)\t:10000 type '[(10000#1.2)]
2765
q)\t:10000 type ':[(10000#1.2)]
16035
q)\t:10000 type '[(100000#1.2)]
27587
q)\t:10000 type ':[(100000#1.2)]
153916

q)\t:10000 type each (10000#1.2)
2774
q)\t:10000 type peach (10000#1.2)
16127

Number of slaves in my env are 2
q)\s
2i
```

Am I missing something, or can we conclude that for a single list as operand applying monadic function with each-both is faster compared to each-prior.

Comment: I think that for simple atomic operations single thread often outperforms using slave threads. Slave threads usually make sense when HDB data across multiple partitions is used, especially if those partitions are stored on different physical devices.

Comment: Agreed - slave threads and peach are only faster if the operation being performed either (a) crunches a large amount of data and is parallelizable and/or (b) returns a small amount of data to minimize overhead of serializing and sending data from slave threads to main thread and vice versa. Your example doesn't fit this mould. However something doesn't seem right with your timings.....the 6x timing difference is not what I'm seeing (I'm seeing only marginally slower times using peach with l64 v3.5) - what OS and what kdb version are you using?

Comment: It can be very hardware dependent, there is the cost of serialization the specific hardware implementation. I'm in fact gettting reduced time with a peached operation of type peach (10000#1.2) to the each version, running 3.6 2019.06.03.. This isn't the case with a more mixed list as with the first example for me

Comment: It is varying significantly based on version. OS in the questions is Linux and kdb version is 3.3.

Comment: `peach` performance (in this particular example) seems to have improved greatly from v3.5 onwards. You could consider upgrading if it's an issue for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any potential multithreading application needs to weigh up the cost of IPC serialization and transmission, against the benefit of concurrent computation. In general, applications will see a benefit from multithreading with

1. Reduced size of inputs and outputs, as this will reduce the IPC overhead to a degree (serialization and transmission will always have an impact)
2. Increasing computational intensity

Given this, I would expect for simple operations such as `type`, that there would be a *slight reduction* in the performance as the input vectors increased when using `peach`, as this would amplify the IPC serialization impact of the threading operation. **However**, I was unable to repeat your results, with my `each` being comparable to `peach`. I would consider upgrading to `3.6` as Terry has suggested, which I believe has a more efficient IPC serialization method, reducing the overhead introduced by multithreading

All of this does not mean that multitheading will not give an improvement to the operations you have tested. For mondadic operations on large input lists (particularly for small input/output), `peach` is **not** a suitable multithreading implementations, as it introduced many many IPC serialization and transmission overheads, with each item in the input being sent individually to a given thread. But given that these operations are easily vectorized and hence will see better performance from .Q.fc (function cut), which will reduce the IPC overhead by chunking the input vector into n blocks and sending those blocks to each of the `s` threads.

```
q)(.z.o;system"s";.z.K;.z.k)
`w64
4i
3.6
2019.07.25
q)\t:100 type each (1000000#1.2)
3995
q)\t:100 type peach (1000000#1.2)
3615
// type can easily be vectorized through a simple lambda {type each x}
q)\t:100 .Q.fc[{type each x};(1000000#1.2)]
1890
```

I'd recommend reading through the whitepaper on [multithreading](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/multi-thread/)